# Grouping and aggregating data in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, logic

I have a Pandas DataFrame containing transaction data, and I want to perform grouping and aggregation operations to analyze the data at different levels. I have tried using the groupby and agg functions, but I'm facing some difficulties in achieving the desired results.

Here is an example of the DataFrame structure and data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Product': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'D'],
    'Transaction_ID': ['id1', 'id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id3', 'id3', 'id4', 'id4', 'id4', 'id5','id6'],
    'Size': ['S', 'M', 'L', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'S', 'S', 'M', 'S','M'],
    'Demand_Qty': [5, 3, 2, 2, 1,2, 1, 4, 1, 1,1]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to perform the following operations:

1. Check if there are multiple sizes in each transaction
2. Check if there are transactions with the same size but multiple quantities
3. total transaction count

I tried using the groupby and agg functions, but I'm not getting the desired output. Here's the code I have tried:

```
product_order_grouped = df1.groupby(['Product', 'Transaction_ID']).agg(
    multiple_sizes_in_transaction=('Size', lambda s: s.nunique() > 1),
    same_sizes_in_transaction=('Size', lambda s: s.nunique() == 1 and df1.loc[s.index, 'Demand_Qty'] > 1)
).reset_index()

product_grouped = product_order_grouped.groupby('Product').agg(
    Total_Transactions=('Transaction_ID', 'count'),
    Transactions_with_Multiple_Sizes=('multiple_sizes_in_transaction', 'sum'),
    Transactions_with_Same_Size_and_Multiple_Quantities=('same_sizes_in_transaction', 'sum'),
).reset_index()

print(product_grouped)
```

The output I'm getting is not as expected. Could someone guide me on how to correctly perform these grouping and aggregation operations on the DataFrame to get the desired results?

---

### Current output

```
  Product  Total_Transactions  Transactions_with_Multiple_Sizes  Transactions_with_Same_Size_and_Multiple_Quantities
0       A                   3                                1                                                 1
1       B                   2                                1                                                 0
2       C                   1                                1                                                 0
3       D                   1                                0                                                 0
```

---

### Expected output

```
  Product  Total_Transactions  Transactions_with_Multiple_Sizes  Transactions_with_Same_Size_and_Multiple_Quantities
0       A                   3                                1                                                 2
1       B                   2                                1                                                 1
2       C                   1                                1                                                 1
3       D                   1                                0                                                 0
```

**logic to get the desired results Transactions_with_Same_Size_and_Multiple_Quantities**

```
   Product Transaction_ID Size  Demand_Qty
0        A            id1    S           5
1        A            id1    M           3
2        A            id2    L           2
3        B            id3    S           2
4        B            id3    M           1
5        B            id3    L           2
6        B            id4    S           1
7        C            id4    S           4
8        C            id4    M           1
9        A            id5    S           1
10       D            id6    M           1
```

**If we just look at Product 'A'**

```
   Product Transaction_ID Size  Demand_Qty
0        A            id1    S           5
1        A            id1    M           3
2        A            id2    L           2
9        A            id5    S           1
```

*Then id1 & id2 are 2 transactions where we have demand qty more than 1 so the value should be 2*

***Similarly, for Products B & C it should be 1 as only 1 Transaction_ID has more than 1 value in demand qty and for & D it is 0***

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to correctly perform these grouping and aggregation operations on the DataFrame to obtain the desired results.

**P.S. -  I am also open if someone can suggest me to look at any other metric that can share better insights on this data || because for example again if we look at Product A there are actually 3 instances where demand is more than 1 so I am not sure if my metrics are good enough to analyse the data**

---

Adding more test Data

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Transaction_ID': [1357778791, 1357779263, 1357779570, 1357779583, 1357779893, 1357779893, 1357782347, 1357782681, 1357782681, 1357783510, 1357784048, 1357784401, 1357784564, 1357784564, 1357784670, 1357784816, 1357784816, 1357785798, 1357786529, 1357787012, 1357787208, 1357787837, 1357788325, 1357788326, 1357788452, 1357788542, 1357788585, 1357788585, 1357789168, 1357789633, 1357789633, 1357790352, 1357790366, 1357790379, 1357790730, 1357792699, 1357794652, 1357795141, 1357795141, 1357795147, 1357795805, 1357796833, 1357797368, 1357797714, 1357797789, 1357798619, 1357799260, 1357799933, 1357802692, 1357802692, 1357802771, 1357802818, 1357803663, 1357804255, 1357804868, 1357805887, 1357805941, 1357807095, 1357807122, 1357807122, 1357807897, 1357808324, 1357808324],
     'Product': [2199692] * 63,
    'Size': [48, 46, 36, 44, 44, 42, 36, 38, 36, 48, 36, 36, 44, 42, 38, 40, 38, 46, 36, 36, 40, 40, 36, 44, 48, 42, 44, 42, 42, 46, 44, 36, 48, 40, 36, 48, 38, 46, 44, 38, 46, 40, 36, 36, 36, 36, 44, 48, 42, 44, 38, 38, 38, 48, 48, 46, 40, 38, 44, 40, 40, 40, 38],
    'Demand_Qty': [1] * 63
    }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Print the DataFrame
print(df1)
```

Comment: The logic for Transactions_with_Same_Size_and_Multiple_Quantities is unclear, how to you obtain 1 and 2? Please break the logic down

Comment: @mozway hey, yes I have updated the question with logic . Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question well. You can try:

```py
def fn(x):
    total_transactions = x["Transaction_ID"].nunique()

    transactions_with_multiple_sizes = (
        x.groupby(x["Transaction_ID"])["Size"].nunique() > 1
    ).sum()

    transactions_with_same_size_and_multiple_quantities = (
        x.groupby("Transaction_ID")["Demand_Qty"].sum() > 1
    ).sum()

    return pd.Series(
        {
            "Total_Transactions": total_transactions,
            "Transactions_with_Multiple_Sizes": int(transactions_with_multiple_sizes),
            "Transactions_with_Same_Size_and_Multiple_Quantities": transactions_with_same_size_and_multiple_quantities,
        }
    )


product_grouped = df1.groupby("Product").apply(fn)
print(product_grouped)
```

Prints:

```
         Total_Transactions  Transactions_with_Multiple_Sizes  Transactions_with_Same_Size_and_Multiple_Quantities
Product                                                                                                           
A                         3                                 1                                                    2
B                         2                                 1                                                    1
C                         1                                 1                                                    1
D                         1                                 0                                                    0
```

---

Initial `df`:

```
   Product Transaction_ID Size  Demand_Qty
0        A            id1    S           5
1        A            id1    M           3
2        A            id2    L           2
3        B            id3    S           2
4        B            id3    M           1
5        B            id3    L           2
6        B            id4    S           1
7        C            id4    S           4
8        C            id4    M           1
9        A            id5    S           1
10       D            id6    M           1
```

Comment: I am so sorry I updated my question but forgot to change the initial df, please have a look at initial df again, with that my example logic will get much clear. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Transactions_with_Multiple_Sizes = no. of transactions where user bought more than 1 size for x product.  for example, someone was confused and bought S&M both. This can help us in understanding that we can expect a return of 1 product.

Transactions_with_Same_Size_and_Multiple_Quantities = where someone bought 2 of a kind. Basically, the user bought 2 or more S articles

Comment: @sdave I've updated my answer. (changed `.any()` to `.sum()`)

Comment: still Transactions_with_Same_Size_and_Multiple_Quantities logic needs to be updated 
```x.groupby(['Transaction_ID', 'Size'])["Demand_Qty"].sum() > 1).sum()```